# Tish'a Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ramban's famous Disputation at Barcelona (against an apostate Jew and a supporting cast of Christian priests) took place in the summer of 1263. This was 229 years before the Jews were expelled from Spain in 1492.

Answer (score 2):

The verse in the Chumash with the lowest gematria is Bamidbar 21:8: וּבְנֵי פַלּוּא אֱלִיאָב. - And the children of Pallu: Eli'av. The gematria of this verse is 229.